# Append multiple dictionary elements to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a big list containing multiple dictionaries, which I can access for example with:

```
>>> papers[0]['TI']
"Presence of tau pathology within fetal neural allografts in patients with Huntington's and Parkinson's disease."
```

I need to access 3 different keys of all the dictionaries in the list (['TI'], ['AB'] and ['MH']), and print them to a .txt file, but at the moment my code only prints out one of the keys (['TI']) of all of the dictionaries. This is what I have:

```
papers = []   # the list of dictionaries

for each in range(0, len(papers)):
    out = []
    try:
        out.append(str(papers[each]['TI']) + "\n" + str(papers[each]['AB']) + "\n" + str(papers[each]['MH']) + "\n")
    except KeyError:
        out.append("MISSING INFORMATION \n")

for index, line in enumerate(out):
    with open(filename+'_{}.txt'.format(index), 'w') as output:
        output.write(line)
```

Note: I added the str() to each papers key because I kept getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

What may be wrong, since I am not able to print the 3 different keys but only one? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you print the values? maybe there's an entry which contains a list (even if most entries contain a string)

Comment: maybe you could append to out the three keys, and not just the first one.

Comment: also note:  `for index, line in enumerate(out):
    with open(filename+'_{}.txt'.format(index), 'w') as output:
        output.write(line)` that's incorrect, swap `with` and `for` lines or you'll write only the last line

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if i swap the with and for lines I am referencing index before i assign it, and also I need to get that number into the filename. I can print the values individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
papers = []   # the list of dictionaries
out = []
# ...
# populate your papers list
# ...
for paper in papers:
    try:
        paper_string = "{TH}\n{AB}\n{MH}\n".format(
            TH=paper['TH'],
            AB=paper['AB'],
            MH=paper['MH'])
     except KeyError:
         paper_string = "MISSING INFORMATION\n"
     finally:
         out.append(paper_string)
```

Comment: using `format` also converts to string. So it hides the issue & is equivalent to OP code (except that it seems more pythonic)

Comment: The nice thing about `format` is that it doesnt create the intermediate strings that `+=` does since all strings are immutable in python.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your out=[] being inside the for loop. With each iteration it is reinitialised to a blank list.

Some minor suggestions:

1. just use for each in papers (no need for range)
2. to get the key for your strings you can use each[key], since each
   represents the current entry in papers which the loop is looking at.

If you just want to quietly go through your list of papers you could do it without the try/except as well, using ifs to make sure you don't create exceptions with missing keys. Here's my testcode:

```
dict1 = {'TI':'baa', 'AB':'baar', 'MH':'maa', 'DK':'maar'} # all keys and more
dict2 = {'TI':'baa', 'AB':'baar', 'MH':'maa', 'DK':'maar'} 
dict3 = {'OG':'moo', 'AG':'moor', 'ND':'raa', 'DG':'raar'} # none of the keys
dict4 = {'TI':'baa', 'AG':'moor', 'MH':'maa', 'DG':'raar'} # Two of the keys 


papers = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4]

out = []

for paper in papers: # Automatically iterates over all list entries in papers.


    # if all papers always have all three keys:
    ##results = ''.join((paper['TI'], '\n', paper['AB'], '\n', paper['MH']))

    ##out.append(results)

    # OR: If they may have only (any) one of the keys:

    results = ''

    if 'TI' in paper: results+=paper['TI']
    if 'AB' in paper: results+='\n'+paper['AB']
    if 'MH' in paper: results+='\n'+paper['MH']

    out.append(results)
```

This is out for the second version:

> ['baa\nbaar\nmaa', 'baa\nbaar\nmaa', '', 'baa\nmaa']

Comment: I did use the out outside the for loop at first and since I was seeing no results I moved it inside the loop, but like Ayodhyankit Paul said, I am using out outside the loop so its place its outside. As for the rest of the code, @sterling baldwin's answer did the trick for me first, but your tip for the missing information is useful so I'll get that into the code as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
papers=[]
out = []

for index,value in enumerate(papers):
    try:
        out.append(str(papers[index]['TH']) + "\n" + str(papers[index]['AB']) + "\n" + str(papers[index]['MH']) + "\n")
    except KeyError:
        out.append("MISSING INFORMATION \n")

    print(out)
```

Comment: I did try at first with 'out' outside the for loop, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. The rest of the code doesn't work as all it prints out are multiple "missing information"'s

Comment: You are appending values in `out` inside loop but you are using `out` outside that current loop.

can you give a sample of list data , what i tried is working for this code , i tried with this data :

https://dpaste.de/8HTy

Comment: do you really need `index` ?: no you don't. Is that solving OP problem?: No.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i just tried with index , she is using range iterator while i am using index no instead of that.

Comment: the issue is probably the input data which is corrupt: i.e: not strings.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre should i delete my answer?

Comment: do as you want, but IMHO it's not bringing anything to the question (which is unclear)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i think loop issue was pointed out by me in this code then rest of answers which are gettin upvotes corrected same issue after me. check the time.